# JSLint: Unexpected ES6 feature

Tags: javascript

I got the message "Unexpected ES6 feature" from the online linter on jsllint.com.

The offending line was this:

```
(t_1=(1+2));
```

But what unexpected ES6 feature is the hinting towards?

The settings were

```
- Assume...   nodejs
- Tolerate... bitwise operators
- Tolerate... messy whitespace
```

and the file starts with  `"use strict";`

The full program:

```
"use strict";
var RUNTIME=(require("/Users/soegaard/Dropbox/GitHub/urlang/runtime.js"));
var cons=RUNTIME.cons;
var NULL=RUNTIME.NULL;
var str=RUNTIME.str;
function displayln(v){return (console.log(v));}
function closure_p(v){return ((Array.isArray(v))&&(v[0]==="CLOS"));}
var result=0;
((function(t_1){
   (t_1=(1+2));
   (result=(displayln(t_1)));
   return result;
  })(undefined));
```

Comment: Yes, it is a function argument. I have added the full program to the question.

Comment: I guess it's just a false positive, but why do you need to wrap every expression into brackets?

Comment: To keep the code generator simple, most expressions are wrapped.

Comment: @soegaard, then you could try disabling es6 warnings by /*jslint es6: true */` or via some config/.rc file

Comment: @andrey Thanks for the tip. The online linter seems to ignore it - guess it is time to use the command line one instead.

Comment: My mistake, I set it to true, and `unexpected` warning disappeared, but it still treats this construction as arrow function and gives another syntax warning

Comment: Alternatively switch to eslint instead.

Comment: @FelixKling That looks as an interesting project. And I think a better fit for my purposes that jslint. Thanks!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

It is treating those expressions wrapped in parenthesis as arrow functions.

Aside, those make your code very hard to read. They aren't needed so please drop them.

Comment: @soegaard what/who wrote it then?

Comment: I am writing a compiler that outputs JavaScript.

Comment: After looking up arrow functions: The syntax for arrow functions include the keyword `=>` so JSLint is guessing somewhat here.

Comment: So, if Daniel is right, then this is a bug in JSLint.

Comment: @Katana314 Given that is uncommon to wrap expressions in a statement position in parentheses I can see that JSLint should react somehow. A simple "don't wrap expressions occurring as a statement in parentheses" would be better than the "Unexpected ES6 feature" especially when it doesn't mention which feature it has detected.

Comment: @soegaard I don't see how it makes sense to single that out though. There are still some situations where you do want parentheses in that situation. `var a = (1+2)*4` has a different result than `var a = 1+2*4`. I wouldn't bother including parentheses where they're not necessary, but there shouldn't be anything wrong with a developer choosing to use them.

Comment: @Katana314  I can't think of a good reason to write  `(expr);` instead of `expr;`. Which was JSLint complained about.

Comment: @soegaard JSLint complained about an ES6 feature, which is wrong; so it's a bug. I don't think they've even considered whether they should call out unneeded parentheses as a warning, and personally I don't think they should bother.

Comment: I agree. Will you file a bug report?

Comment: Why was this answer down voted? Daniel spotted what triggered the linter.