# Unexpected ES6 feature '='

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jslint

This minified JavaScript code works just fine:

```
document.onkeyup=function(a){a=a||window.event;a.altKey&&121===a.which&&(my_variable=!0===my_variable?!1:!0)};
```

However, JSLint complains two things about it:

> Unexpected ES6 feature '='
>
> Expected '=>' and instead saw '}'

I can't determine how to edit the code to satisfy JSLint, and I'm especially curious how '=' could be an unexpected feature of ES6. Can anyone help?

Comment: Looks like a bug in JSLint: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32655797/jslint-unexpected-es6-feature?rq=1  But why do you need to lint generated/minified code?

Answer (score -1):

`(x=1)` causes the same issue.

`(my_variable=!0===my_variable?!1:!0)` makes JSLint assume that you are declaring an arrow function `(myvariable=...) => ...` and JSLint doesn't yet accept default arguments for these (Unexpected ES6 feature '=') and complains about the missing arrow `=>` (Expected '=>' and instead saw '}').

It is obviously a bug within JSLint.

Solution: Don't use JSLint...